# Need to change admin MYSQL password on debian server that has plesk

Tags: debian, passwords, mysql, plesk

the plesk interface of one of my servers crashed today with the message ERROR: `

```
> PleskDBException: Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect():
> Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
> (Error code: 1045) (Abstract.php:69)
```

I know that on the different support websites they say to change the password for admin but none of the tutorials worked for me. 
Ffirst step was to stop mysql service and that part worked, but when it comes to start mysql server without password (mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &) it does not work and i'm stuck at that part. Does anyone have a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [article](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213364309-Unable-to-access-Plesk-Access-denied-for-user-admin-localhost-using-password-YES-) for instructions. You can add the skip-grant-tables option into /etc/mysql/my.cnf after that you should be able to start the database server and reset the password.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about "our article" as in yours or the one you're affiliated with, correct?